# Storing large Numpy arrays in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, numpy

I am trying to order the results of my calculations, which are stored in numpy arrays of size from 1kb to maybe hundreds of MB or even 1GB. I tried to use cPickle to convert them to BSON and to put them into MongoDB, but MongoDB-documents are limited to 16Mb.

Does it make sense to switch to something like CouchDB or should I just put the files in a folder and save the link in MongoDB? I am just using the database locally, so I can search my datasets quickly. I don't need access from multiple machines or concurrency.

Edit: This would be an example of such an array:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.random.rand(8000, 4000)

print A.nbytes


Out[3]: 256000000
```

Comment: Can you give us a short sample extract of your arrays? Are you storing a huge list of primitives (double or something) in there or structured documents again? Would it be an option to store every array element as a separate document perhaps?

Comment: Your array example is a random array of dimension 8000x4000, how do you envision searching over this array i.e find element on `array[500][123]` ? Remember database is not like a flat file on disk, you don't store the whole information into a single row/document.

Comment: No I have some data about this matrix, e.g. wheater data (air pressure, rain, etc) and the matrix is the result. Then I'd like to search my previous simulations, which then return the whole array for a given air pressure range. Then the DB says 10 simulations are in the range and these are the according matrices